# installing MariaDB source code on manjaro

Tags: linux, mariadb, manjaro

i'm a linux newbie and i wanna install mariadb 10.2 which doesn't exist in the the repo. so i wanna install it from the source code [mariadb-10.2.12.tar.gz](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.2.12/) here, so how can i install it

Comment: Don't bother to use source code; download and install the binary from https://downloads.mariadb.org/

Comment: Or use docker... ha

Comment: If you are using Manjaro, you should be able to use this arch linux package: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=mariadb
Or you can just look at the packages install script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in arch:-

```
- sudo pacman -S mariadb
- sudo  mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
- sudo systemctl start mariadb 
- sudo mysql_secure_installation 
- mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pacman -S mariadb
```

and I installed mariadb successfuly